# In Java Swing, why is this font size incorrect?

Tags: java, swing, font-size

I've tried several versions of Java Swing, but this font size is always incorrect, when will it be fixed ?

```
JButton lButton=new JButton("\u24c1");
lButton.setFont(new Font("Monospaced",0,23));

JButton mButton=new JButton("\u24c2");               // (M) is always smaller, why ?!
mButton.setFont(new Font("Monospaced",0,23));

JButton nButton=new JButton("\u24c3");
nButton.setFont(new Font("Monospaced",0,23));
```

As you can see below, the (M) in the middle is always smaller, why ?!

[image]

Comment: What if you change line number 3 to JButton mButton=new JButton("\u24c1"); ? Looks to me like "\u24c2" simply corresponds to a smaller size circle.

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JRNg.png) on Windows 10 and Java 8

Answer (score 2):

The middle M most likely comes from a different font than the others. The circled M character is part of "emoji" (it can be used as a "metro" sign) so there are more fonts that include it than the circled L or N. Compare https://unicode-table.com/en/24C1/ and https://unicode-table.com/en/24C2/

To fix this, you may want to consider using a specific font instead of the "monospaced" logical font, as according to the [java.awt.Font API specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html):

> Typically, each logical font name maps to several physical fonts in order to cover a large range of characters

Comment: But don't you think this is a bug in jdk/jre, I used the same font, same size in my code, it should show me the same type, same size instead, shouldn't Java Swing automatically do that for me ? How about other circled characters, they all look the same size.

Comment: Not a bug in my opinion. "Monospaced" is an abstraction that potentially chooses a different type face for every character,  so you did not "use the same font". If you want text to be displayed consistently on all systems, use a specific concrete type face.